# Script or tool for adding users to server with ssh keypair login

Tags: linux, ssh, admin

Is there a tool or a common script for adding users to a linux server that also configures the ssh keys?

For example, I found I can automate creation of users with `useradd` or `adduser`, and it is even possible to setup an account with password login with e.g. `adduser --password my_password`. However, that still leaves me having to add the `.ssh` folders and files and set the correct permissions, which in my case leaves plenty of room for typos.

What I am looking for is something like

`adduser --ssh user_public_key`

where `user_public_key` is key provided to me by the new user.

I imagine there might be an existing tool for this, but my duckducking didn't turn up anything useful.

Comment: In my version of Ubuntu, manual page of `adduser` talks about "Optional custom add-ons" located at `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local`. Maybe there is an ssh addon? I have no idea where to look for one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (for centos, plus enables docker)

```
set -euo pipefail

DEV_GROUP="somegroup"
sudo groupadd --force "${DEV_GROUP}"

function adduser() {
    local var_user="$1"
    shift 
    local var_ssh_pub_key="$*"
    id --user "${var_user}" &>/dev/null || sudo useradd --gid "${DEV_GROUP}" --groups wheel,docker "${var_user}"
    echo "${var_user} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" | sudo tee "/etc/sudoers.d/${var_user}"
    sudo --user "${var_user}" mkdir -p "/home/${var_user}/.ssh"
    sudo --user "${var_user}" touch "/home/${var_user}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    echo "${var_ssh_pub_key}" | sudo --user "${var_user}" tee "/home/${var_user}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
}

adduser someuser ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1.... user@host
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a script as root:

```
$ mkdir ~username/.ssh
$ cat user_public_key >> ~username/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ chown -R username ~username/.ssh
```

Comment: Doesn't this create a new keypair for the user? My usecase is different, I am trying to setup a user account with *user provided* public key for authentication.

Comment: Yes, it does. Can't your users simply use `ssh-copy-id`?

Comment: The users don't have access to the machine until I create their accounts. While I am unfamiliar with the `ssh-copy-id` command, I think I would have to enable password authentication for this to work. I agree that this would be a viable workaround, but it beats the purpose of requiring keypairs for login.

Comment: I mean this answer works if I am ok with sending new private keys to users instead of users sending me their public keys, but that doesn't seem like a good security practice.

Comment: If you want users to be able to authenticate using their keys you have to put contents of their public key they sent to you in `~user/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Exactly! Maybe I should rephrase the question, I am looking for a tool that sets up the .ssh folders for newly added users ideally in one command.